# Задать пароль от приватного ключа удостоверяющего центра в командной строке

Tags: bash, openssl, openvpn

Задача: Мне необходимо автоматизировать процесс создания пользователей для ovpn. Будет использоваться `awx`, поэтому необходимо написать команду так чтобы все что может затребовать команда передавать через атрибуты или как-нибудь по другому. Суть в том чтобы ничего не запрашивало c консоли.

Пользовательские ключи и сертификаты созданы. Далее необходимо авторизовать удостоверяющим центром пользовательский сертификат. При такой процедуре требует пароль от приватного ключа CA. Я с помощью аттрибута `-keyfile` указал ссылку на этот файл. Однако у меня все равно требует `Enter pass phrase for /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/ca.key:`. Вот команда:

```
sudo openssl ca -batch -config /etc/openvpn/keys/safessl-easyrsa.cnf -out /tmp/keys/client.crt -in /tmp/keys/client_unpass.crt -keyfile /etc/openvpn/keys/private/ca.key -cert /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
```

Не делаю средствами easy-rsa, т.к. не соответствует моим требованиям. ( Для защиты, избегаю инструкции `nopass`, а там нету атрибута для проброса пароля).

Вопрос: Можно ли пробросить пароль от приватного ключа CA в команду? Сделать что то вроде `echo "Password" > sudo openssl ca -batch -config /etc/openvpn/keys/safessl-easyrsa.cnf -out /tmp/keys/client.crt -in /tmp/keys/client_unpass.crt -keyfile /etc/openvpn/keys/private/ca.key -cert /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt`

Comment: `sudo -S` читает пароль из `/dev/stdin`

Comment: @PakUula вопрос не о sudo-пароле

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пароль к ключу передается через опцию `-passin`. Openssl поддерживает несколько [схем передачи пароля](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl.html#Pass-Phrase-Options):

- `-passin pass:Password` - пароль `Password` задан прямо в командной строке,
- `-passin env:PSWD_VAR` - пароль задан в переменной окружения `PSWD_VAR`
- `-passin file:/path/to/key/pwd.txt` - пароль задан в файле `/path/to/key/pwd.txt`
- `-passin stdin` - пароль читать из `/dev/stdin`
- `-passin fd:6` - пароль читать из файлового дескриптора 6

В вашем примере это будет так:

```
echo "Password" | sudo \
  openssl ca -batch -config /etc/openvpn/keys/safessl-easyrsa.cnf \
    -out /tmp/keys/client.crt -in /tmp/keys/client_unpass.crt \
    -keyfile /etc/openvpn/keys/private/ca.key -passin stdin \
    -cert /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
```

Без `echo`:

```
sudo \
  openssl ca -batch -config /etc/openvpn/keys/safessl-easyrsa.cnf \
    -out /tmp/keys/client.crt -in /tmp/keys/client_unpass.crt \
    -keyfile /etc/openvpn/keys/private/ca.key -passin pass:Password \
    -cert /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
```